# Riemann integral by definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Someone asked me this question, and I thought it was a good idea to post the answer here.

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac1q\right),&\ \frac pq\in\mathbb Q, \ q\neq0, \ \ p,q \text{ coprime }\\ 0,&\ \text{ otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable and find $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: The function $\sin $ can be replaced with any function $g$ such that $g(1/n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and the conclusion remains same. The version $g(x) =x$ is more common  as an exercise in many books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who knows measure theory, it is obvious that $f=0$ a.e., and the answer is trivial.  But the point is to do this at the level of Riemann integrals.

Because of the density of the irrationals, it is clear that any lower sum will be zero; so we only need to work with upper sums.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $n_0>2/\varepsilon$. Let $P$ be a partition  $0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1$, with $\max\{x_{j+1}-x_j:\ j=0,\ldots,n-1\}<1/n_0^3$. For each interval, we have 
$$
f_j:=\max\{f(x):\ x\in[x_j,x_{j+1}]\}=\sin\left(\frac 1{q_j}\right),
$$
with $p_j/q_j\in[x_j,x_{j+1}]$. Let $A=\{j:\ q_j<n_0\}$; since the number of rationals in $[0,1]$, with denominator less than $n$, is $n(n-1)/2$, we have $|A|\leq n_0(n_0-1)/2\leq n_0^2$. Then, writing $\Delta_j=x_{j+1}-x_j$,
\begin{align}
U(f,P)&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f_j\,\Delta_j=\sum_{j\in A} f_j\Delta_j+\sum_{j\not\in A}f_j\,\Delta_j
\leq \frac{|A|}{n_0^3}+\frac1{n_0}\sum_{j\not\in A}\,\Delta_j\\ \ \\
&\leq\frac{n_0^2}{n_0^3}+\frac1{n_0}=\frac2{n_0}<\varepsilon.
\end{align}
The above computation shows that given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for every partition $P$ with diameter less than $\delta$, $U(f,P)<\varepsilon$. Thus the infimum of the upper sums is zero, $f$ is integrable, and $$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=0.$$

Comment: Nice approach. It is always better to use simpler tools when available although more powerful tools like measure theory can provide more insight. +1

Comment: Yew. Besides, students are usually exposed to these ideas before they learn about measure theory.